# make: 'srtp2/srtp.h' file not found

Tags: c, macos, homebrew

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to compile a C project on macOS using make

### The Problem

make is failing to find srtp, even though it's installed via brew

```
 'srtp2/srtp.h' file not found
#include <srtp2/srtp.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

### What I tried

homebrew says it's installed

```
Warning: srtp 2.4.2_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.4.2_1, run:
  brew reinstall srtp
```

... and linked

```
▶ brew link srtp
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1
To relink, run:
  brew unlink srtp && brew link srtp
```

pkg-config can find it

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libsrtp2

-I/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1/lib -lsrtp2
```

pkg config path seems fine

```
▶ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

path seems to contain the `.pc` file for srtp

```
▶ locate /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libsrtp
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libsrtp2.pc
```

the .pc files content

```
▶ cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libsrtp2.pc
prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1
exec_prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libsrtp2
Version: 2.4.2
Description: Library for SRTP (Secure Realtime Transport Protocol)

Libs: -L${libdir} -lsrtp2
Libs.private: -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l_1/lib -lcrypto
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

and the path in the `${prefix}/include` is also legit

```
▶ head /usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1/include/srtp2/srtp.h
/*
 * srtp.h
 *
 * interface to libsrtp
 *
 * David A. McGrew
 * Cisco Systems, Inc.
 */
/*
 *
```

### Question

How do I debug this and why is make not finding srtp?

### EDIT

I changed my PKG_CONFIG in ./zshrc from

```
#export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

to

```
#export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

because apparently I'm supposed to point at ALL `*.pc` files, not just one. This broke more stuff.
Apparently, not linking directly to the .pc files makes stuff worse.

`make -d` is now giving me

```
Package 'openssl' has no Name: field
In file included from ./src/hash/ov_hash.c:34:
include/ov_hash.h:37:10: fatal error: 'openssl/evp.h' file not found
#include <openssl/evp.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, for some reason pkg config is unable to use the `*.pc` files in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.
No clue why.

### EDIT 2

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"

# openssl pkg config hacky shit that works but 
# does the same thing the .pc file does that doesnt work
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
# srtp still no dice
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/srtp/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
# this doesnt work either
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1/include:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

So apparently, if I add the openssl include manually to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in `~/.zshrc` it finds openssl.
So the problem is pkg-config itself, since it seems to have issues resolving or finding the `*.pc` files.

HOWEVER: When I do the same thing with srtp, it still does not work.

Comment: Is `Cellar` on your path for include files?  That's not a usual place for them.

Comment: `▶ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` returns `/usr/local/Cellar/srtp/2.4.2_1/include/srtp2/srtp.h`